# PhantomJs and PHP: stream_get_contents stops reading randomly

Tags: php, shell, laravel, stream, phantomjs

`stream_get_contents()` is really freaking me out. It's been twenty-four hours of non-stop debugging and testing solutions from all over the Internet to make it work.

It basically just stops reading randomly.

What I am doing is loading a webpage with PhantomJs through `proc_open()` then load the result reading the pipes given by the process. The problem is that whenever I try to read either pipes, stdout and stderr, `stream_get_contents()` blocks:

- It reads *nothing* out of STDOUT pipe.
- It blocks randomly after at some point without completing the reading of STDERR pipe.

I know that it blocks at a random point because I tried to debug it with this code:

```php
while(! feof($pipes[2])) {    
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2], 50);   
}

echo "Finished!";
```

The page never manages to echo *"Finished!"*.

The library I am using is [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs).

I am totally sure it's not an issue from my side because if I attempt to execute phantomjs on its own with the temporary file generated from the library, phantomjs executes properly and it gives me the correct result.

I have tested the code both on Windows and Linux OS (with nginx).

The point where the library gives me trouble approximately is [here](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/blob/master/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php#L101).

Nevertheless, this is the PHP code (simplifed) I am using to web scrape a page:

```php
$client = Client::getInstance();        
$client->setBinDir(Config::get('phantomjs.bin'));
$client->setPhantomJs(Config::get('phantomjs.path'));
$client->setPhantomLoader(Config::get('phantomjs.loader'));

$client->debug(true);

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();

$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('http://google.com');
$request->setTimeout("120000");

$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$client->send($request, $response);
```

- Why in the world does `stream_get_contents()` not read *at all* or *stops randomly* while reading?**
- Why does it work through (windows/linux) shell but it does not from PHP?
- How do I fix this issue?
- Could it be a PHP issue?
- Could it be a System (firewall, etc) issue?

**Interesting Fact**

> A library I have built to web scrape a website and return its result
> *used* to work a month ago. The same code does not work anymore right now without changing anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved by using temporary files instead of stream pipes in `proc_open()`.

Furthermore, PhantomJs 1.9.8 with *[php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)* **SHOULD NOT** be installed as it gives issues with parsing the data out of the files. [It's a known issue.](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697)

*[I have released a repository that fixes the problem to whoever wishes to use it.](https://github.com/GiampaoloFalqui/php-phantomjs)*

---

## Installation

Add these lines of code in your application composer.json.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/GiampaoloFalqui/php-phantomjs"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "3.*"
    }
},
```